# How to dynamically set a grunt <%= var %>

Tags: gruntjs

How do I change the value of a grunt variable (<%= var %>)
before running a task?

I have the following code, but it does not seem to process the json and exchange the placeholders(<%= var %>) with the new value.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
var modules = ['a','b','c'];

grunt.initConfig({
    module: module,
    som_task: {
        blah: {
            files: 'test/<%= module %>',['<%= module %>']
        }
    }
});
grunt.registerTask('release-all', 'abc', function() {
    for (var module in modules) {
        grunt.task.run(['setModule:'+module,'release']);    
    }

});
grunt.registerTask('setModule', 'change the variable in the ', function(module) {
    grunt.config('module',module);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. I created a function to return the config object with a different variable and then re-init it before running my tasks.

```
function getConfig(value) {
    return {
        "value":value,
        ...
    };
}
grunt.registerTask('change', 'Swap Value', function(passValue) {
    grunt.initConfig(getConfig(passValue));
});

//set the default
grunt.initConfig(getConfig("initialValue"));

//run the task and pass in the new value before running your other task
runt.task.run(['change:newValue']);
```